# Automated code navigation for finding all types of exceptions thrown?

Tags: java, source-code, tools, editor-navigation

There is a java code base based on the Spring Boot framework. As an activity I want to navigate the code path of every API method to check for the checked exceptions that are thrown at different points in the code path.

Now I am aware that the exceptions thrown in the code path would have to be either caught & handled or thrown to the caller but the problem here is that I have a base class for the exceptions thrown by the application which is caught or thrown by the API methods. As a result I don't know about the particular exceptions that can be expected in the method call chain. Please find below a simple code example to compliment my problem statement:

```
class Controller { 
    public void apiMethod() throws CustomException {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.method1();//throws CustomException1
        service.method2();//throws CustomException2
    }
}

class Service {
    public void method1() throws CustomException1 {
        throw new CustomException1();   
    }

    public void method2() throws CustomException2 {
        throw new CustomException2();

    }
}

class CustomException extends Exception {

}

class CustomException1 extends CustomException {

}

class CustomException2 extends CustomException {

}
```

As is evident from the code that the API method is aware that exceptions of type **CustomException** would be thrown by the call chain but is unaware about the exact exceptions that can be thrown. Now I want to know an automated way to know all the different type of exceptions that are thrown by the method call chain and not just the parent exception.

Please let me know if more information or clarity is required.

Comment: _"Now I want to know an automated way to do this."_ To do what exactly?

Comment: Updated the question above.

Comment: This would require an appropriate static code analysis tool to retrieve this information. Questionable however is what you would do with this information.

Comment: Well I require this for knowing exactly what different kinds of exceptions can be thrown by my method so that I can document this for any consumer of my API or methods.

Comment: Isn't that documented well enough with the `throws` attributes?

Comment: This is a good question. I am not aware of any tool for your task. You are getting negative scores, because your question suggests that you are trying to do something which is against how the exception system should be used(design smell). When an interface specifies „throws CustomException”, the user should be prepared to catch all subclasses of CustomException. He should even be prepared for subclasses which aren’t even implemented today.

Comment: I agree this(throw or catch the parent exception) is how it should be done. It is just that I require this for documentation(as mentioned above) else the consumer of my APIs will be unaware as to what all types of exceptions can be thrown. Static code analysis can help but will need to experiment with the different tools.

Comment: Have you considered changing the `throws`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, but with [swagger](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations) you can annotate controller methods to create documentation.

The advantage is, that you can see more directly, what kind of exceptions may happen, because you have your code already open in front of you or have it even written some minutes ago. At this point you can think quite good about a description for it. It is not as automated as scanning the code or something similar. But it would generate your documentation while building the application, that could be convenient for you.

Otherwise you need to first find the possible exceptions, extend the result with additional information and then populate it somewhere. This seems to be complex to me.